# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access

I have made lines of code as seen :

`

```
Public Class frm_login_a188500
    Private Sub btn_login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_login.Click

        Dim mysql As String = "SELECT COUNT( * ) AS NUM_MATCHES FROM TBL_USERS_A188500 WHERE FLD_USERNAME ='" & txt_username.Text & "’ and FLD_PASSWORD ='" &
txt_password.Text & "’"
        Dim mydatatable As New DataTable

        Dim myreader As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(mysql, myconnection)

        myreader.Fill(mydatatable)

        Dim num_matches As String = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("NUM_MATCHES")

        If num_matches = 1 Then

            frm_mainmenu_a188500.Show()
            Me.Hide()

        Else
            txt_username.Text = ""
            txt_password.Text = ""
            MsgBox("Incorrect Username or Password")

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

`

However, there's an error :

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'FLD_USERNAME ='’ and FLD_PASSWORD ='’'.'

Expecting to get the error so that I can fix it.

Comment: You show 2 slanted apostrophes in the SQL. Access will not like that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use smart quotes:

```
Dim mysql As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM_MATCHES FROM TBL_USERS_A188500 WHERE FLD_USERNAME ='" & txt_username.Text & "' And FLD_PASSWORD ='" & txt_password.Text & "'"
```